# Is the function defined by $f(x+1)=f(x)+f(1), f(2)=1$ just $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$?

Tags: functions, induction

Is the function defined by $f(x+1)=f(x)+f(1), f(2)=1$ just $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$?

I was solving this exercise:
A function $f$ of real variable satisfies $f(x+1)=f(x)+f(1), f(2)=1$ for any $x$. Determine $f(5)$.

Well, since $f(2)=f(1)+f(1)=2f(1)$, then $f(1)=\frac{1}{2}$.

$f(3)=3f(1)$, then $f(4)=4f(1)$, then $f(5)=5f(1)=\frac{5}{2}$

Then I began wondering if the function was just $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$.
For the naturals and integers I can prove by induction, since:
$f(1)=\frac{1}{2}$, assuming $f(k)=\frac{k}{2}$, then $f(k+1)=f(k)+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{k}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{k+1}{2}$.

Since $f(-1)=-f(1)$, follows similarly to the integers.

But can I prove to the non-integer reals? I don't know how...

Comment: Like Mathcounterexample.net showed, the answer is no, but i think you will find Cauchy's functional equation interesting: [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is negative.

For example any map
$$f_{\alpha,k}(x) = x/2 +\alpha \sin(2k\pi x)$$

where $\alpha$ is a real and $k$ an integer would do the job.

More generally a map $f(x)=x/2+ g(x)$ where $g$ is any periodical map with period equal to $1$ and $g(0)=0$ satisfies the initial requirements.